# Positive trace (all diagonal entries are positive) implies semipositive definite?

Tags: linear-algebra, symmetric-matrices, positive-semidefinite

I am working on a matrix with all the diagonal entries are strictly positive while every other entry is strictly negative. This matrix is symmetric as well. 
I want to show that this matrix is semipositive definite.
Since the trace is strictly positive, I know that the sum of the all eigenvalues (the roots of characteristic polynomial) is also strictly positive, but I am not sure whether each eigenvalues are nonnegative. 
What is the best way to show this matrix is semipositive definite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not true. $\begin{bmatrix}1 & -2\\-2 & 1\end{bmatrix}$ is a simple counter example